# How to control colour of this Unicode character in Edge, without changing font? (Current code works fine with Firefox.)

Tags: html, css

The following code is intended to print a red version of the Unicode character with HTML code &#9724. It does this in Firefox, but it prints black in Edge. How can I amend the code so that it will print red, as desired, in both browsers?

```
<html>
<body>
<span style="color:#f00";>&#9724;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I opened the page in both Firefox and Edge.

Changing the span to

```
<span style="color:#f00;
     font-family:Segoe UI Symbol">&#9724;</span>
```

works, but is there a way to do it that doesn't involve changing the font?

Comment: Try removing the semicolon `;` or move it within the quotes `""`, like so `style="color:#f00;"`. Your issue doesn't have anything to do with the font, you just made a typo.

Comment: Many thanks, @Emiel. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid, you must place the semi-colon within the double quotes. Additionally, the semi-colon is optional for the last style.

```html
<span style="color: #f00;">&#9724;</span>
<!--                    ^ Either remove the semi-colon or place it inside the quotes -->
<span style="color: #f00; font-family: Segoe UI Symbol;">&#9724;</span>
```

Edit: This works out of the box, without the need to change the font.

```html
<span style="color: #f00;">&#9724;</span>
```